# How to simulate preview of HTML on different email clients

Tags: email, preview, newsletter, email-client

I have a website for newsletters, and I'd like to give my customers the possibility to preview how the message will be displayed on Outlook (various versions), Thunderbird, LotusNotes, GMail, etc...

I know there are many websites and applications out there that do this trick, but I want to implement this feature inside my website.

The newsletter website is written in PHP on a Linux standalone server which I have total control on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 main services that provide email testing. [Litmus](https://litmus.com/) and [Email on Acid](http://www.emailonacid.com/).

Email is very hard to accurately simulate across email clients, and I wouldn't suggest trying to do it outside of a service that has virtual machines running the tests for you.

Take a look at the API's ([Litmus](https://litmus.com/api) and [EOA](http://www.emailonacid.com/api)) of each of these 2 services. Email on Acid seems most cost effective option. Using the API of one of these two services is the only (accurate) option I would suggest.